# Apache Tomcat Default App

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

I am using ubuntu-16.04 and have been trying to work with Tomcat. My version is: Apache Tomcat/8.0.36.

I have an app in **http://localhost:8080/mynewapp** which i wanted to access as root app, that means i want to see my app when i access **http://127.0.0.1:8080**

Please, help me about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

1. Remove the out-of-the-box `ROOT/` directory from tomcat and rename your war file to `ROOT.war` before deploying it.
2. Deploy your war as (from your example) `war_name.war` and configure the [context root](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html) in `conf/server.xml` to use your war file :

   ```
   <Context path="" docBase="war_name" debug="0" reloadable="true"></Context>
   ```

The first one is easier, but a little more kludgy. The second one is probably the more elegant way to do it.

Source:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/5328636/2983312

Also, 127.0.0.1 should resolve to localhost by default.  If it does not, you can add an entry to `/etc/hosts` as root.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

Comment: Thanks. I did succeed by first method (replacinf ROOT with my app). But i am not clear with other one.